# Accessing a React Native module from other native code

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I use a [native module](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info) that works great for getting device info in React Native, in the JS code.  I'd like to also make use of it's functionality in other native (Objective-C) code.

Is it possible to access functionality of React Native custom modules from other native code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either access the functionality directly (using `-[RNDeviceInfo deviceName]` method) or using the way React Native is accessing it, that is:

```
RNDeviceInfo *rn = [[RNDeviceInfo alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Device Name: %@", [rn constantsToExport][@"model"]);
```

Comment: To refine this a bit, [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1033) also works and I think reduces the overhead by not instantiating a second copy of the class in question.  Save a reference to the bridge in the AppDelegate `_bridge = rootView.bridge;` then access the module through it `NSString *deviceName = [_bridge.modules[@"RNDeviceInfo"] constantsToExport][@"model"];`.  Log it out: `NSLog(@"Device Name: %@", deviceName);`

Comment: You get to learn with me.  This call has now changed due to the deprecation of `bridge.modules` in favor of lazy loading the modules `NSString *deviceName = [[_bridge moduleForName:@"RNDeviceInfo"] constantsToExport][@"model"];`

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, that is admittedly a bit of a kludge.  It does work, but I would imagine this is far from ideal.

At the top of the class that utilizes this code:

```
@interface RNDeviceInfo ()
- (NSString*) deviceName;
@end
```

Then I can make use of it like so:

```
RNDeviceInfo *rn = [[RNDeviceInfo alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Device Name: %@", [rn deviceName]);
```